# How to show Text depends on switch case in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, switch-statement

I am working with SwiftUI, I have one switch case function, depend on that switch case i want to show diff color and text.

```
    func status(status: Status){
            switch status {
            case .accepted:
//text "accepted"
                //green text   
    
            case .standby:
//text "standby"
                //yellow text
    
            case .notAllowed:
//text "notAllowed"
                 //red text
            }
        }

VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Test")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply switch over `status` inside the body of your view and assign the correct `String` and `foregroundColor` to your `Text` inside each `case.

```
struct StatusView: View {
    let status: Status

    var body: some View {
        switch status {
        case .accepted:
            Text("accepted")
                .foregroundColor(.green)
        case .standby:
            Text("standby")
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
        case .notAllowed:
            Text("not allowed")
                .foregroundColor(.red)
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you can modify `Status`, you can simply assign a `String` `rawValue` to it, then displaying the appropriate text based on its value is even easier.

```
enum Status: String {
    case accepted
    case standby
    case notAllowed
}

struct StatusView: View {
    let status: Status

    var body: some View {
        Text(status.rawValue)
            .foregroundColor(statusColor(status: status))
    }

    private func statusColor(status: Status) -> Color {
        switch status {
        case .accepted:
            return .green
        case .standby:
            return .yellow
        case .notAllowed:
            return .red
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.. Its perfect..sorry to ask more...but can you modify answer if I have diff text based on condition ..i modified question

Comment: @DávidPásztor: There is no need to that `VStack` in your answer anymore.

Comment: @swiftPunk good catch, that was a leftover from copying OP's code

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated and refactored answer based on **David** answer, with this way you do not need that `ststusColor` function anymore and you can access the **colorValue** every where in your project instead of last answer that was accessible only inside `StatusView`.

```
struct StatusView: View {
    
    let status: Status
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text(status.rawValue)
            .foregroundColor(status.colorValue)
        
    }
    
}


enum Status: String {
    
    case accepted
    case standby
    case notAllowed
    
    var colorValue: Color {
        switch self {
        case .accepted:
            return .green
        case .standby:
            return .yellow
        case .notAllowed:
            return .red
        }
    }
    
}
```